# Edit a file with single quotes in the filename in Vim

Tags: vim, gnome-terminal, terminator

I've run into an odd problem in Vim.  I would like to drag and drop a file from my desktop or file manager into Vim and edit it.  Gvim handles this behavior correctly.

When I attempt to do the same thing in console Vim, the  path to the file name is inserted instead.  For example, if I drag and drop the file /home/myuser/foo.matic, it will apply the text string '/home/myuser/foo.matic' to the current buffer.

If I type :edit, then drag and drop the file name, Vim treats '/home/myuser/foo.matic' as a new directory.

I believe the problem here is the quotes before and after the file path.  These appear to be inserted by both gnome-terminal and terminator.  Is there a way to strip these quotes from the file name when dragging and dropping?  Alternatively, is there a way for Vim to ignore the quotes?

Comment: It seems a bit weird to use drag&drop with terminal vim. For graphical use, there is gVim. I'd rather type `:e foo.matic` in vim or `vim foo.matic` in the terminal. Another way to go is `gvim -p --remote-tab-silent foo.matic` to open the file in gvim in a new tab.

Comment: I've found recently that screen redraw weirdness happen far less in terminal Vim.  Since I use very little of gVim's extra GUI functionality, it made sense to me to try using terminal Vim instead.  Whenever it makes sense, I'll drag a file into the editor rather than open it with :e or NERD Tree.

Comment: It looks like I can use --remote-tab-silent with terminal Vim as well.  This might be a good option.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can’t make vim own `:e` command to do what you need, but you can define your own one. Most straightforward solution - make shell parse what was intended to be parsed by the shell - is listed below:

```
command -nargs=? -bang -bar E :execute "e<bang> ".fnameescape(system("echo -n ".<q-args>))
```

. This command accepts only `:e[!] {file}` variant, no `+cmd` and `++opts` are allowed.

Comment: This seems to solve my problem with dragging files into Vim.  It requires that I type :e before dragging, but that is acceptable for as much as I actually require the dragging of files.  Thank you ZyX.

Comment: @rustushki Not typing `:e` before dragging, but `:E`. I don’t believe it is possible to something better (though there may be a pointer somewhere in gnome-terminal documentation, terminal emulators have quite a lot features compared to old terminals and framebuffer). Definitely not without patching vim: documentation states that drag'n'drop works only in GTK, win16 and win32 GUIs.